# Url.Action built in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to do the following in jquery/javascript but getting an problem with the Url.Action bit.

Old style which interates through an IEnumerable of my model

```
>     > <div class="listview small" id="results"> @foreach (var item in Model)
>     > {   <a href="#" class="list shadow">   <div class="list-content">  
>     > <img src="@Url.Action("GetPhotoThumbnail", new { sname =
>     > item.SamAccountName, width = 75, height = 75 })" alt="meek"
>     > class="icon" />   <div class="data">   <span
>     > class="list-title">@item.DisplayName</span>   <span
>     > class="list-subtitle">Information Technology Dept</span>   <span
>     > class="list-remark">Don't smack the pony!</span>   </div>   </div>  
>     > </a>}   </div>
```

New idea where I'm getting the results now through jquery/ajax to have the data returned for autocomplete input.

```
$personsLists.prepend('<li><a href="' + url + '" class="list shadow">'
 + '<div class="list-content">'
 + '<img class="icon" alt="' + displayname + '" src="@Url.Action("GetPhotoThumbnail", new { sname = samaccountname, width = 75, height = 75 })">'
 + '<div class="data">'
 + '<span class="list-title">' + url + '</span>'
 + '<span class="list-subtitle">Information Technology Dept</span>'
 + '<span class="list-remark">Don\'t smack the pony!</span>'
 + '</div></a></li>');
```

The problem is understanding how the @Url.Action works really on the DOM.  Can someone point me in the right direction please.

---

**[EDIT]**
I guess I can't do this as I'm trying to execute server side code while processing the html to load on the DOM.  The point of this Url.Action was to load a thumbnail of the person.  Would the road to follow be to action the GetPhotoThumbnail via another function when the data gets loaded?

**[EDIT]**
So i've taken this approach.  On the line where I'm building the img tag i'm calling a function called getThumbnail.

```
+ '<img class="icon" alt="' + displayname + '" src="data:image/png;base64,' + getThumbnail(samaccountname) + '">'

function getThumbnail(query) {
            if (query.length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetThumb", "Person")',
                    data: { sname: query, width: 75, height: 75 },
                    contentType: "image/png",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data != "")
                            $('#tempimg').html(
                            $('<img/>', {
                                src: data,
                                alt: 'this is a super chart'
                            })
                        );
                    },
                    error: function (error, txtStatus) {
                        console.log(txtStatus);
                        console.log('error');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

this is causing me a headache now as the (data) is not returning correctly?!?  The controller passes through a FileContentResult so onwards i guess.

Thanks

Comment: It's really confusing what you're trying to do. You're using an ajax request to get an image - that's binary data that's returned, right? Then you set that to your `src` attribute - never gonna work.

Comment: Yeah i thought that Tim.  If honest i'm out of my depth hence the stupidity.  The goal to achieve is an autocomplete where the data brought back from the controller is a persons data (ie Photo and Name).  Works brilliant until i introduce the img.  The $personsLists.prepend is where the data brought back rebuilds the div array to load.  So as you type the html is changed on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked this out in the end.  Full code [enter link description here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44655/total-noob-for-javascript-your-thoughts).

Basically set out the image in the controller to return Json of the byte array, then set a variable from the return json str.

```
function a(){
  var r = {
    placeholder: null,
    img : null,
    image: function { my ajax call -> r.img = jsonresult },
    imageThumbnail: function () {
       r.image();
       r.placeholder = "<img class='p-icon' id='pid' src='data:image/png;base64," + r.img + "' />"
      }      
    }

   return r;
 }
```

Using the above similar code I was able to push [r] to the div of my choosing ie $('#mydiv').append(r)

Anyhow check out the link for more details.  I have posted this over to code review for thoughts and comments.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to create a URL template that your client-side code can reuse. Something like:

In your view:

```
<script language="javascript">
  var thumbnailTemplate = "@Url.Action("GetPhotoThumbnail", new { sname = "_sname_", width = 75, height = 75 })";
  function getThumbnail(name) {
     return thumbnailTemplate.replace("_sname_", name);
  }
</script>
```

Just watch out for URI encoding - if there's a chance that name will contain URI-reserved characters, you'll need to escape them.